# "WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL" and "CertificateException: PKIX path building failed" when accessing external WS

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, websphere-liberty, websphere

The exception is thrown when accessing an external SOAP webservice:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException:

 Failed to access the WSDL at:
  https://<IP>/ws/services/Webservice?wsdl.

It failed with:

 java.security.cert.CertificateException:
  PKIX path building failed:

   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

I cannot access this URL, I need to send the WAR file for my customer and he needs to deploy in another environment, an IBM Liberty app server, in which he says three certificates were already configured: root, intermediate and the true certificate itself.

Insisting something had to be refactored in code, I did this before calling the external endpoint, passing the certificate as the `certificateFile` parameter (they're all inside src/main/resources):

```java
Certificate certificate = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(certificateFile));

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("server", certificate);

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

if (url.contains("https")) {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
} else if (url.contains("http")) {
    new URL(url).openConnection();
}
```

What really are the steps to trust these certificates and where these steps must be done (the application, the server, the machine JVM, whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

If this is running inside Liberty, it shouldn't need any special code. They probably need to add the certificate from the remote webservice to Liberty's trust store as documented here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_add_trust_cert.html

Comment: Executed these commands right now, restarted the server, but the exception persists. I'm still seeking for another solution.